# Why is 10 times phosphate-buffered saline more acidic (~6.9) than 1 time phosphate-buffered saline (~7.4)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, ph, salt

Recently, I've been told that similar pH shift (of about 0.5 units) was observed with [20 times NPS](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3101525/) solution as well.

In case of NPS the authors provide the following recipe for the 20 times solution:
H2O 900 ml,
(NH4)2SO4 66 g,
KH2PO4 136 g,
Na2HPO4 142 g.
with expected pH to be about 6.75.

Why is that?

Comment: Asking for answers and not providing relevant details, purpose or background of questions are contradictory decisions.
Also, questions should be self containing, making sense even without link target availablity.

Comment: What is the meaning of the words "10xPBS stock" ? Is it ten times something ? Ten times what ? What is PBS ? What is 1xsolution ?

Comment: Thanks! Edited for better understanding

Comment: Activity coefficients of ions with bigger charge ($\ce{HPO4^2-}$ versus $\ce{H2PO4-}$)  drop with growing ionic strength faster, therefore the phosphate buffer gets more acidic with higher concentrations, and vice versa.

Comment: @Poutnik, thanks. Maybe you can post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity coefficients of ions with bigger charge ($\ce{HPO4^2−}$ versus $\ce{H2PO4−}$) drop with growing ionic strength faster, therefore the phosphate buffer gets more acidic with higher concentrations, and vice versa.